# Putting event handlers inside NextJS _document -- and relationship between NextJS pages and React SPA

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm learning NextJS and am trying to wrap my head around the difference between server-rendered and client-side React code -- while NextJS seems great, I'm having some trouble conceptually understanding the difference between the two types of rendering and what those differences *mean*.

For instance, I came across the following comment in the NextJS documentation, in the section describing `_document``

```
// _document is only rendered on the server side and not on the client side
// Event handlers like onClick can't be added to this file
```

Why can one not put event handlers in `_document`?  What is the difference between this and putting them 'client side'?

Also I'm somewhat confused because NextJS seems to be oriented around building 'pages' -- that is, there's support for adding `<HEADER>`, etc, as if we were building a static website.  But if I were to build a React SPA, there's only one page, no?  One can simulate different 'pages' using the React router, but the actual containing HTML (header, body, etc) remains the same, no? That is, we never really leave the actual HTML page?

I can *use* NextJS OK -- following through the documentation's tutorials -- but clearly *conceptually* I'm missing the forest for the trees.  Any clues or pointers much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pages/_app.js` is where you need to client-side codes. It is shared between all pages.

`pages/_document.js` only runs in SSR. so you need to put relevant code there.

Saying that, you only need to create these pages if you need to modify the normal behaviour of the app and customise it in your way.

**SSR** means Server side rendering and it happens when you type url in urlbar and press enter or when you refresh the page with refresh button.

**CSR** Client Side Rendering on the other hand is the way of SPA(single page app). so the URL change but there is no server call. It look for resources in `pages` directory for routing.

**Next HEAD** is way to manipulate the header tags like `meta`, `title` etc. in every page. It will give you freedom of customising head tag.

Comment: Thanks.  One thing: why does it say you can't add `onClick` handlers to `_doc.js`?

Comment: Because _document.js only runs on server.

Comment: Indeed, but if you would, ELI5, what does 'run on the server' mean exactly?  As I understand it with SSR the page is _served_ from the server, meaning it passes it to the browser which renders it.  How is that different from 'running' on the server?  That is, in 'regular' HTML (non-SPA), you can use `onClick` handlers, as they're served from the server and 'run' in the browser.  When I think of 'run on the server'  I think of code like PHP, Node or Python.  Is that what's going on with `_doc`, it's actually executing on the server in some fashion, not served to the browser?  Or both?

Comment: @MoHo Then how can I add onTouchStart to the body tag? Because body inside pages/_documen